# Writing pandas DataFrame to JSON in unicode

Tags: python, json, pandas, unicode

I'm trying to write a pandas DataFrame containing unicode to json, but the built in `.to_json` function escapes the characters. How do I fix this?

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['τ', 'a', 1], ['π', 'b', 2]])
df.to_json('df.json')
```

This gives:

```
{"0":{"0":"\u03c4","1":"\u03c0"},"1":{"0":"a","1":"b"},"2":{"0":1,"1":2}}
```

Which differs from the desired result:

```
{"0":{"0":"τ","1":"π"},"1":{"0":"a","1":"b"},"2":{"0":1,"1":2}}
```

---

I have tried adding the `force_ascii=False` argument:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['τ', 'a', 1], ['π', 'b', 2]])
df.to_json('df.json', force_ascii=False)
```

But this gives the following error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u03c4' in position 11: character maps to <undefined>
```

---

I'm using WinPython 3.4.4.2 64bit with pandas 0.18.0

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Opening a file with the encoding set to utf-8, and then passing that file to the `.to_json` function fixes the problem:

```
with open('df.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    df.to_json(file, force_ascii=False)
```

gives the correct:

```
{"0":{"0":"τ","1":"π"},"1":{"0":"a","1":"b"},"2":{"0":1,"1":2}}
```

Note: it does still require the `force_ascii=False` argument.

Comment: for some reason this just wasn't working for me so what I did was load the dumped JSON again, `eval`d the required field and dumped the json back again.

Answer (score 2):

There is also another way of doing the same. Because JSON consists of keys (strings in double quotes) and values (strings, numbers, nested JSONs or arrays) and because it's very similar to Python's dictionaries, then you can use simple conversion and string operations to get JSON from Pandas DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['τ', 'a', 1], ['π', 'b', 2]])

# convert index values to string (when they're something else - JSON requires strings for keys)
df.index = df.index.map(str)
# convert column names to string (when they're something else - JSON requires strings for keys)
df.columns = df.columns.map(str)

# convert DataFrame to dict, dict to string and simply jsonify quotes from single to double quotes  
js = str(df.to_dict()).replace("'", '"')
print(js) # print or write to file or return as REST...anything you want
```

Output:

```
{"0": {"0": "τ", "1": "π"}, "1": {"0": "a", "1": "b"}, "2": {"0": 1, "1": 2}}
```

UPDATE:
Based on note from @Swier (thank you) there could be a problem with strings containing double quotes in the original dataframe. `df.jsonify()` would escape them (i.e. `'"a"'` would produce `"\\"a\\""` in JSON format). With help of small update in the string approach is possible to handle this too. Complete example:

```
import pandas as pd

def run_jsonifier(df):
    # convert index values to string (when they're something else)
    df.index = df.index.map(str)
    # convert column names to string (when they're something else)
    df.columns = df.columns.map(str)

    # convert DataFrame to dict and dict to string
    js = str(df.to_dict())
    #store indices of double quote marks in string for later update
    idx = [i for i, _ in enumerate(js) if _ == '"']
    # jsonify quotes from single to double quotes  
    js = js.replace("'", '"')
    # add \ to original double quotes to make it json-like escape sequence 
    for add, i in enumerate(idx):
        js = js[:i+add] + '\\' + js[i+add:] 
    return js

# define double-quotes-rich dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame([['τ', '"a"', 1], ['π', 'this" breaks >>"<""< ', 2]])

# run our function to convert dataframe to json
print(run_jsonifier(df))
# run original `to_json()` to see difference
print(df.to_json())
```

Output:

```
{"0": {"0": "τ", "1": "π"}, "1": {"0": "\"a\"", "1": "this\" breaks >>\"<\"\"< "}, "2": {"0": 1, "1": 2}}
{"0":{"0":"\u03c4","1":"\u03c0"},"1":{"0":"\"a\"","1":"this\" breaks >>\"<\"\"< "},"2":{"0":1,"1":2}}
```

Comment: Casting the result to string and replacing quotes will produce invalid json if there's a quote in any of the text values. `pd.DataFrame([['τ', 'a', 1], ['π', 'this breaks >>"<< ', 2]])` will produce `{"0": {"0": "τ", "1": "π"}, "1": {"0": "a", "1": "this breaks >>"<< "}, "2": {"0": 1, "1": 2}}`

Comment: Thank you @Swier - I've updated my answer to solve such issue

Answer (score 2):

This works fine for Mac OS

df.to_json('df.json', force_ascii=False)

Comment: Yes, it would work on for macOS since the the OS would be using "UTF-8" for I/O. The problem in the question is more around not wanting to escape sequences and that on Windows, the user was encountering I/O encoding issues.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue, although I wasn't writing to file. The solution was to encode the string as 'utf-8':
`df.to_json(force_ascii=False).encode('utf-8')`

Comment: `df.to_json()` writes the dataframe to a file, and it has no return value, so there's no string to encode at that point.

Comment: @stackoverflowed force_ascii=False fix my issue. tnx