# Does pandas to_json have an encoding parameter?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, to-json

I want to make a dataframe a json object.

For example,

```
function f():
    ...
    ...
    ...
    return dataframe.to_json(orient='records',force_ascii=False)
```

but to_json does not have encoding paramter like `to_csv`

How do I encode with utf-8 in the case of `to_json`?

thank you for reading.

Comment: Format code as code please.

Comment: [No taglines please](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: No spelling errors (`josn` in the title) please.

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: Thanks for comment. I tried it but there is not encoding parameter error occur

Comment: did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39612240/writing-pandas-dataframe-to-json-in-unicode

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing pandas DataFrame to JSON in unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39612240/writing-pandas-dataframe-to-json-in-unicode)